How is it possible for dconf and gsettings to disagree about a setting?
While investigating this issue I ran into something really weird:
❯ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces
4
❯ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/num-workspaces
'1'

This shouldn't be possible, right? What could be going on?

How exactly do you reproduce this behavior? After setting with dconf-editor I get consistent values. At first glance it seems these two have very different ways of getting the configuration file, so I'm guessing it has to do with that...
I suggest running strace -e openat with both commands to see which files are actually used.

Oh nevermind, there a pretty reasonable answer on the link you sent. gsettings expects an integer and receives a string, so it falls back to the default setting (all credit goes to 'jtojnar')

Based on the findings in the issue mentioned above:

The gsettings schema says the type is "i". (I had set it to a string because of a misleading error message.)
The mapping from the type string, "i", to the actual type (my emphasis) says "i" is a "signed 32 bit integer".
nixpkgs shows that pkgs.lib.gvariant.type.int32 = "i", so that's the right connection.
mkInt32 "Returns the GVariant int32 from the given Nix int value."

So, by setting num-workspaces = mkInt32 1; I finally get the right response:
❯ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces
1

